# How do I convert a cell array w/ different data formats to a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

So my main objective is to take a matrix of form

```
 matrix = [a, 1; b, 2; c, 3]
```

and a list of identifiers in matrix[:,1]

```
 list = [a; c]
```

and generate a new matrix

```
 new_matrix = [a, 1;c, 3]
```

My problem is I need to import the data that would be used in 'matrix' from a tab-delimited text file. To get this data into Matlab I use the code:

```
 matrix_open = fopen(fn_matrix, 'r');
 matrix = textscan(matrix_open, '%c %d', 'Delimiter', '\t');
```

which outputs a cell array of two 3x1 arrays. I want to get this into one 3x2 matrix where the first column is a character, and the second column an integer (these data formats will be different in my implementation).

So far I've tried the code:

```
 matrix_1 = cell2mat(matrix(1,1));
 matrix_2 = cell2mat(matrix(1,2));
 matrix = horzcat(matrix_1, matrix_2)
```

but this is returning a 3x2 matrix where the second column is empty.

If I just use

```
 cell2mat(matrix)
```

it says it can't do it because of the different data formats.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't mix data types in a matrix, so you have to use cell arrays, but that shouldn't be a problem that stops you from doing what you want.

Comment: What are `a` and `c`? Are they doubles? Are they characters? Also can `matrix` hold duplicates of the values in `list`?

Comment: in Matlab, a "Matrix" of different data type is possible with a construct called a ... `cell array`. Bingo, you are already there. If you really want to mix types in an array, then `cell array` is the only Matlab type that can do that. However, if your `text` type are only single characters, you could easily use `double` to handle them as numeric type until such time you need them back in acsii format. This would allow you to have one single matrix (full of numeric elements).

Answer (score 0):

This is the help of matlab for the cell2mat function:

```
cell2mat Convert the contents of a cell array into a single matrix.
    M = cell2mat(C) converts a multidimensional cell array with contents of
    the same data type into a single matrix. The contents of C must be able
    to concatenate into a hyperrectangle. Moreover, for each pair of
    neighboring cells, the dimensions of the cell's contents must match,
    excluding the dimension in which the cells are neighbors. This constraint
    must hold true for neighboring cells along all of the cell array's
    dimensions.
```

From what I understand the contents you want to put in a matrix should be of the same type otherwise why do you want a matrix? you could simply create a new cell array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have a *normal matrix* with characters and numbers. That's why `cell2mat` won't work here. But you can store different datatypes in a cell-array. Use `cellstr` for the strings/characters and `num2cell` for the integers to convert the contents of `matrix`. If you have other datatypes, use an appropriate function for this step. Then assign them to the columns of an empty cell-array.

*Here is the code:*

```
fn_matrix = 'data.txt';
matrix_open = fopen(fn_matrix, 'r');
matrix = textscan(matrix_open, '%c %d', 'Delimiter', '\t');

X = cell(size(matrix{1},1),2);
X(:,1) = cellstr(matrix{1});
X(:,2) = num2cell(matrix{2});
```

*The result:*

```
X = 
    'a'    [1]
    'b'    [2]
    'c'    [3]
```

---

Now we can do the second part of the question. Extracting the entries where the letter matches with one of the list. Therefore you can use `ismember` and logical indexing like this:

```
list = ['a'; 'c'];

sel = ismember(X(:,1),list);

Y(:,1) = X(sel,1);
Y(:,2) = X(sel,2);
```

*The result here:*

```
Y = 
    'a'    [1]
    'c'    [3]
```